# what is causing this memory leak in netty

Tags: netty

I have two server process, they communicate with two socket connections. Both connections are sending message oneway only.(one for c->s, one for s->c).

The server and the client bootstrap initialized with OioServerSocketChannelFactory / OioClientSocketChannelFactory respectively.

After some profiling, found object of these three classes never release(on both side). I don't use these classes directly and I only keep reference to two Channel object.

```
java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue$Node 1005351 32171232  
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels$2 1005351 24128424  
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ChannelRunnableWrapper 1005351 48256848
```

What kind of object leaked in my code might cause these objects not release?

UPDATE: the environment, jdk7u7, centos6 64bit, netty 3.5.3

Comment: Are you closing the channel once the connection is done?

Comment: no. the connection won't close until the server process shutdown.

Comment: And the client I talking about is also a server process, it just mean the connection start by this server, and this server process have only one instance. so the total connection on either side is two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good chance this is a bug of netty. After I change OioServerSocketChannelFactory / OioClientSocketChannelFactory to NioServerSocketChannelFactory / NioClientSocketChannelFactory the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

This was because of a bug in Netty Oio impl. The bug was fixed as part of 3.5.4.Final. So please upgrade to 3.5.4.Final or 3.5.5.Final.

See [1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/520